Allowing Moderators/high rep users to accept answers on behalf of askers
Relates to Asking users to accept answer when they comment that it answers their question.
Has there been any discussion of allowing users with high levels of rep to accept answers on behalf of posters?
My experience lately has been a lot of community bot modifications that effectively "push" unanswered questions. Many of them actually contain one or two answers that are quite good. I've also noticed a trend in people asking questions, seeing the answer they were looking for and oftentimes abandoning the site/question even after comments from them thanking the answerer and suggestions from readers of accepting the answer.
A feature where it would require 3 such users to accept an answer would be good (viz. the close question feature). I would also like to think that those with high reps on these sites would carry some form of credibility in the respective substack. I also recognize that it is not moderators responsibilities nor am I proposing they be responsible for this.
A potential issue might arise with a large group of high rep users disagreeing on what is the acceptable answer but could this not be settled by a vote setting? i.e. One answer receives 4 accepts and another receives 3 accepts so the former is the indicated correct answer. At the very least it would remove clutter.
This addresses the answer to the 2011 question Should moderators be allowed to accept an answer on behalf of original poster? [duplicate]:

Moderators do not moderate posts for technical accuracy, nor do they
have a mechanism for changing the accepted answer.

Likewise from 2009 there is Moderators accepting answers on users behalf after a certain time period to which I agree, it is not moderators responsibility. Should we not give this ability to high rep users in the presence of unaccepted answers after a certain amount of time passed? I don't think this creates a concentration of power on what is deemed correct, especially if we afford the asker the ultimate veto (e.g. they can change the accepted answer).
Overall, I find the number of answered questions a little annoying and I think we curtail the criticisms posed in the latter 2 questions linked above by allowing prominent users to take on this responsibility. I know it isn't perfect and we can't possibly backtrack through all of those questions but I think this would be a step in the right direction. Interested to hear thoughts on the matter. I can't imagine this would be that complicated to implement but I may be wrong.

An accept is a choice by the asker. So it doesn't makes sense for anyone else to accept. It is a sign that it presumably was most helpful to the asker. It isn't a sign of any other quality. Score votes are. So there is no need for anyone else to accept anyway. PS This post gives no reason for your proposal. You do suggest "credibility" & "what is deemed correct". But you don't clearly state your goal & why it is good. "in the right direction" Towards what?

This question is similar to: Moderators accepting answers on user's behalf after a certain time period. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"My experience lately has been a lot of community bot modifications that effectively "push" unanswered questions." from Why does the Community ♦︎︎ user only bump questions with at least one answer?, "a question with a 0 votes answer only needs a single upvote during the bump to come off the Unanswered list"

Question is already closed so I don't think it's worth investing more time into the discussion. The number of downvotes is pretty indicative that the meta isn't interested in changing this feature and/or is closed to new contributors. Sorry for not posting an immediately sufficient question, it's my first time.
I think I just disagree that the answer acceptance should reflect what is helpful and should be something that is helpful to both askers and people consulting this site for question/answers after the fact. The former is the point of this site as I've read and so I'll just drop this.

Downvotes on META sites should not be interpreted as personal attacks or persecution. Here, downvotes  expresses the reader's opposition to request and not opposition to the author of the request. Perhaps the number and speed of downvotes show that the subject has already been exhausted here and on other META sites.

Yeah this is true @AugustoVasques, thank you.

I would prefer to get rid of answer acceptance altogether. Voting is the signal for usefulness for both answers and questions on SE.

The purpose of the accepted answer is what the asker found helpful. The community can't possibly choose what the asker found helpful. Up voting and down voting exists for what the community finds helpful. If the community Up-Votes repeatedly an answer, they have accepted said answer. In other words, a system already exists for people other than the asker to "accept" an answer.

That's pretty much what the answers in the dupe say.

I know, sorry, I didn't see that...@ShadowWizard
